Expected value of copula density function
I have a copula density function $c(u, v)$ (I can assume that $c(u, v)$ is continuous). I want to prove that there is an upper bound $M$ for the following expected value:
$$ \mathbb{E} (|\log c(U_1, U_2)|) < M < \infty,$$
where $U_1$ and $U_2$ are two uniform distributions.
Thoughts: since $U_1$ and $U_2$ are bounded and $c(u, v)$ and $\log(x)$ are continuous I had an idea that $|\log c(U_1, U_2)|$ could be also bounded, but this logic breaks, as $c(u, v)$ could be "blowing" at 0 (e.g., Clayton copula).
I also had in mind inequality $\mathbb{E}|X| \le \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X^2)}$, so that I could work with $\log^2 c(U_1, U_2)$, but still I have no idea where to move from here...

It cannot be bounded. Consider the case where $U_1=U_2$: The copula has no density, but can be approximated by a sequence $c_n$ of densities such that $\lim_n\int[0,1]^2|\log c_n(u,v)du dv=\infty.$

@LetacGérard, what do you mean by "copula has no density"? I want to work only with copulas that have continuous densities

What is a copula? Just the joint distribution of $U_1,U_2$ on $[0,1]^2$ such that the margins $U_1$ and $U_2$ are uniform. For instance it can be concentrated on a diagonal of the square $[0,1]^2$ with no density with respect to the Lebesgue measure $du dv.$

@LetacGérard, I understand that copula could be not differentiable (i.e., do not have density), but in my question I assume that copula $C(u, v)$ has density $c(u, v)$ and moreover this density is continuous.

Take two small squares of size $1/n, $ say  $OABC$ and $IA'B'C'$ one having corner on $O=(0,0)$ the other on $I=(1,1)$ take the Lebesgue measure in the polygon $AA'B'C'CB$ and choose a proper density(*) in the the two small squares such that you get a copula of density $c_n(u,v)$. Then $$ \int[|\log c_n(u,v)|]\to_{n\to\infty } \infty.$$

@LetacGérard, in this case $c_n(u, v)$ is not continuous, is it? If I got it correctly, then $c_n(u, v)$ will be not continuous on the borders of $OABC$ and $IA'B'C'$.

I know a way to build a density on the small squares I have not checked if my construction is continuous. Modifications are possible in order to have $c$ to be $C^{\infty}$.Why is is important for you?  Anyway, this would not change the existence of a counter example to your conjecture (I hope that we agree on the fact that $c$ is a density, not a distribution function).
